# Is conditional statement in Makefile valid syntax

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have the following Makefile

```
~/w/i/craft-api git:develop ❯❯❯ cat Makefile                                                                                     ⏎ ✱ ◼
test:
    echo "TODO: write tests"
generate-toc:
    if ! [ -x "$(command -v doctoc)" ]; then
        echo "Missing doctoc. Run 'npm install doctoc -g' first"
    else
        doctoc ./README.md
    fi
```

I'm encountering this error

```
~/w/i/craft-api git:develop ❯❯❯ make generate-toc                                                                                  ✱ ◼
if ! [ -x "" ]; then
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [generate-toc] Error 2
```

What is incorrect in my Makefile syntax / usage?

## edit 1

Adding line-continuing backslashes doesn't appear to fix the issue:

```
~/w/i/craft-api git:develop ❯❯❯ cat Makefile                                                                                     ⏎ ✱ ◼
test:
    echo "TODO: write tests"
generate-toc:
    if ! [ -x "$(command -v doctoc)" ]; then \
      echo "Missing doctoc. Run 'npm install doctoc -g' first" \
    else \
        doctoc ./README.md \
    fi
~/w/i/craft-api git:develop ❯❯❯ make generate-toc                                                                                  ✱ ◼
if ! [ -x "" ]; then \
      echo "Missing doctoc. Run 'npm install doctoc -g' first" \
    else \
        doctoc ./README.md \
    fi
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [generate-toc] Error 2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every line is treated as a separate command and is passed to a different shell instance. You can use `\` continuations to combine all of the lines so make knows to pass them as one long string to a single shell. This removes the newlines so you also need to add `;` at the end of each command.

```
if ! [ -x "$$(command -v doctoc)" ]; then \
    echo "Missing doctoc. Run 'npm install doctoc -g' first"; \
else \
    doctoc ./README.md; \
fi
```

You'll also want to escape the `$`, otherwise make will interpret it rather than the shell.

Comment: You missed the required `;` at the end of the `echo` line. Without it the `else` (and everything else) is seen as part of the `echo` arguments and the `if` statement isn't closed.

Comment: The missing `;` was the issue. Thanks for explaining that.